# Parse comments with SoupStrainer

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

How can you use SoupStrainer to parse for comments?

I know how to use BeautifulSoup to parse for comments, but I'd like to do this with SoupStrainer to speed up my code. Is this possible?

Example:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup,Comment
import requests

txt = requests.get('https://www.basketball-reference.com/boxscores/202012220BRK.html').text

sp = BeautifulSoup(txt,'lxml')
comment = sp.find(text=lambda text:isinstance(text, Comment) \
                 and 'line_score' in text)
```

This works as intended. But I would like to add a `parse_only` argument to `BeautifulSoup()` to only parse for comments from the start.

**Personal Attempts**

I don't really know where to start because the only way I know how to parse for comments doesn't appear to directly translate to `SoupStrainer`:

```
ss = SoupStrainer(text=lambda text:isinstance(text, Comment))
sp = BeautifulSoup(txt,'lxml',parse_only=ss)
print(sp)
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

This obviously did not work, unfortunately.

I've also tried to pass a string argument:

```
ss = SoupStrainer("comment")
sp = BeautifulSoup(txt,'lxml',parse_only=ss)
print(sp)
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Also no luck.

Comment: Hey @Machetes0602 Welcome to SO! can you specify any code and URL link so it will be easy to understand!

Answer (score 0):

SoupStrainer works by specifying the the items to be parsed in a BeautifulSoup object. Either it's a comment or any other parts of a webpage you may want to point to it directly via something like xpath, or css selector. This helps to figure out the necessary tags to keep and to omit. Then we can only parse the necessary parts/tags by BeautifulSoup.

You might find this [link](https://medium.com/codex/using-beautiful-soups-soupstrainer-to-save-time-and-memory-when-web-scraping-ea1dbd2e886f) useful to get you started with SoupStrainer.